# Measure horizontal lengths of multiple ROI

Tags: imagej

I would like to measure the horizontal lengths of multiple ROI. I tried Feret's diameter, but it only gives the longest distance between any two points along the selection boundary. I tried bounding rectangle, but I suppose the rectangles are tilted to obtain the minimum bounding rectangle.

Does anyone have another idea? Because clearly, the selection boundaries fit nicely to the ROI - so how could I extract that information, i.e. the xy-coordinates of the fits? Thanks in advance

PS: I did not write ROIs because 'Region of Interests' makes no sense

Comment: Cool, seems that the bounding rectangle is axis-aligned, so seems at least a proper approximation to horizontal length. https://forum.image.sc/t/tilted-aligned-bounding-rectangle-in-imagej/22167

Comment: This question is off-topic here (not a programming question), and it has received an answer on the image.sc forum linked in the other comment, so let's close it here.